# Java webstart requires window to use translucency-compatible graphics configuration

Tags: java, linux, graphics, java-web-start

I'm trying to start a Java Webstart application under Java 6u45 (also have tried 7u17 & 7u15) under Linux (Lubuntu 13.10) and I'm getting this error:

```
ERROR officemate.OfficeMate$ExceptionGroup.uncaughtException(OfficeMate.java:359)  1419 15:38:14 [AWT-EventQueue-0]  - Uncaught exception in : AWT-EventQueue-0
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The window must use a translucency-compatible graphics configuration
    at com.sun.awt.AWTUtilities.setWindowOpaque(AWTUtilities.java:378)
    at au.com.ordermate.guicore.progress.VersionSplashWindow.<init>(VersionSplashWindow.java:62)
    at au.com.ordermate.guicore.progress.VersionSplashWindow.<init>(VersionSplashWindow.java:81)
    at officemate.OfficeMate$1.run(OfficeMate.java:125)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:209)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:672)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(EventQueue.java:81)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:633)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:631)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:642)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:269)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:184)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:174)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:169)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at officemate.OfficeMate.getApplicationFrame(OfficeMate.java:270)
    at officemate.OfficeMate$ExceptionGroup$2$1.run(OfficeMate.java:370)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:209)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:672)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(EventQueue.java:81)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:633)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:631)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:642)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:269)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:184)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:174)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:169)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)
```

I'm using XFCE4 with 'display composition' enabled. This is a very old notebook though so there maybe problems getting translucency working. Is there a way to disable it for a webstart application?

**UPDATE**

It does work under Unity

Comment: I'm not sure this has anything to do with Java Web Start. Simply a problem with the environment that the program is being executed on not supporting translucency. What distro/version of Linux?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what your question is or what you're trying to achieve. But, you might consider wrapping the code that is calling `setWindowOpaque()` with a try-catch to catch the `IllegalArgumentException` so that it doesn't interfere with the rest of your code.

Comment: I'm using lubuntu and I don't have access to the code, the only way I start this program is through web start and the code is locked away on a black box on the network (PACOM camera system). Can you fake translucency? or tell Java not to use translucency?